# Reactive extensions Sample or Throttle?

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I have a listBox and am observing when items are selected:

```
selectedItems.Subscribe(DoWorkWIthSelectedItems);
```

The observable returns an array of viewModel items and in `DoWorkWIthSelectedItems` I go through the list of selected items and do some work.  However, since the user may be spamming selections on/off pretty rapidly, whenever work is done on an item, I don't want any work to be done on that item again for 30 seconds.  After 30 seconds, if the item is selected again, go ahead and work on it.

Is there an Rx way to do this?  I am not sure if it would be Sample or Throttle.  Furthermore, I don't know if with Rx I am able to distinguish between items in the array that are good to be worked on or should be ignored.  Would I need an additional property on the viewModel item to indicate some 'working' state?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you consider putting a filter on the underlying collection source so that the item is filtered out until it becomes eligible again?

Comment: @GarryVass Hmm. Don't think I can do that since there are other observers of this data that require all the data to flow through as it arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what there's going to have to be some state. I think your simplest solution would be something like (pseudocode)

```
var recentlyUsed = new ConcurrentDictionary<T, DateTime>();
...
selectedItems
    .Do(/* remove expired items from recentlyUsed */)
    .Where(/* items are not in recently used */)
    .Do(/* add items to recently used */)
    .Subscribe(DoWorkWIthSelectedItems);
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  Based on all the things Rx helps with I wasn't sure if it had some tricks up its sleeve to do this on its own too but I was headed towards the same conclusion. I think in my DoWork method I will add the worked on items to a list and use an ObservableTimer to remove the items after the time limit passes.

Comment: You could probably do some magic with `Window` but I don't know how you would do it and I don't think it would be more effective in any way.